# How to return the PageView to its initial state in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a quiz app and at first everything works fine, but when I do a quiz the first time, it does the correct or incorrect answer check perfectly.

But when I go back to quiz without restarting the app just navigating from one page to another the PageView does not reset its state again.

Before taking the quiz
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40NHG.png)

After I do the quiz and I want to do it again without restart the app, I get the checked answers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoeXA.png)

How to return the PageView to its initial state without restart the app

Here is my code:

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quizapp/src/models/quiz_model.dart';
import 'package:quizapp/src/screens/result_screen.dart';

class QuizScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const QuizScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<QuizScreen> createState() => _QuizScreenState();
}

class _QuizScreenState extends State<QuizScreen> {
  int _questionNumber = 1;
  late PageController _controller;
  int _score = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [

          Expanded(
            child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                child: PageView.builder(
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  controller: _controller,
                  itemCount: questions.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final _question = questions[index];

                    return Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 16,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            _question.text,
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 16,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                  child: Column(
                            children: _question.options
                                .map((option) => GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        Future.delayed(
                                            const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                                            () {
                                          if (_questionNumber <
                                              questions.length) {
                                            _controller.nextPage(
                                                duration: const Duration(
                                                    milliseconds: 250),
                                                curve: Curves.easeInExpo);
                                            setState(() {
                                              if (option.isCorrect == true) {
                                                _score++;
                                              }
                                            });
                                            setState(() {
                                              _questionNumber++;
                                              // _isLocked = false;
                                            });
                                          } else {
                                            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                                context,
                                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                                  builder: (context) =>
                                                      ResultScreen(
                                                          score: _score),
                                                ));
                                          }
                                        });
                                        if (_question.isLocked) {
                                          return;
                                        } else {
                                          setState(() {
                                            _question.isLocked = true;
                                            _question.selectedOption = option;
                                          });
                                        }
                                      },
                                      child: Container(
                                        height: 50,
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                            vertical: 8),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: const Color(0xFF6949FD),
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                            border: Border.all(
                                                color: getColorForOption(
                                                    option, _question))),
                                        child: Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              option.text,
                                              style: const TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 18,
                                                  color: Colors.white),
                                            ),
                                            const SizedBox(width: 10),
                                            getIconForOption(option, _question)
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ))
                                .toList(),
                          )))
                        ]);
                  },
                )),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }

  Color getColorForOption(Option option, Question _question) {
    final isSelected = option == _question.selectedOption;
    if (_question.isLocked) {
      if (isSelected) {
        return option.isCorrect ? Colors.green : Colors.red;
      } else if (option.isCorrect) {
        return Colors.green;
      }
    }
    return const Color(0xFF6949FD);
  }

  Widget getIconForOption(Option option, Question _question) {
    final isSelected = option == _question.selectedOption;
    if (_question.isLocked) {
      if (isSelected) {
        return option.isCorrect
            ? const Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.green)
            : const Icon(Icons.cancel, color: Colors.red);
      } else if (option.isCorrect) {
        return const Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.green);
      }
    }
    return const SizedBox.shrink();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to restart the app when you go back or press a button. You can wrap `Scaffold()` with `WillPopScope()` to restart when you back. You can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phoenix) package to restart.
If you need to save the score, you can save it in local storage. Another easy package for this is [get_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage).

```
dependencies:
flutter_phoenix: ^1.1.0
```

```
runApp(Phoenix(child: const MyApp()));
```

```
WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    Phoenix.rebirth(context);
  },
  child: Scaffold())
```